# Windows Authentication in IIS Express doesnt pick up user details

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I recently started playing with windows authentication. Due to some requirement to collect user details under our domain without asking credentials, I started with windows authentication.

Im working in VS2015 and the application is running in IIS Express. For windows authentication I enabled windows authentication is Web.config as below

```
<authentication mode="Windows">

</authentication>
```

Then altered the iis express config script to this

```
<windowsAuthentication enabled="true">
    <providers>
        <add value="Negotiate" />
        <add value="NTLM" />
    </providers>
</windowsAuthentication>
```

and also this one

```
<add name="WindowsAuthenticationModule" lockItem="false" />
```

under modules

Then this one

under **section group name authentication**

```
<section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

then I specified it in my source of a web page.

```
<h3><%= User.Identity.Name %></h3>
```

But it doesnt returns anything when running from VS. But if I deploy this to Real IIS with windows authentication only enabled it shows the current user name inside the H3

Really havent got an idea what I missed or what I did wrong...

Comment: Have you also disabled the anonymous authentication?

Comment: I disabled Anonymousauthentication under <authentication> where I enabled windows authentication

Comment: Can you check the properties for your project to make sure they're set up for Windows Auth? In solution explorer single click on the asp.net project and then open the properties pane (F4 if not pinned) > check `Anonymous Authentication` = `Disabled`, `Windows Authentication` = `Enabled`

Comment: Thats perfect.. I was setup Windows Authentication in common config file under documents. Here for projects it still shows as disabled... I changed it and its working fine

Comment: "Then altered the iis express config script to this", which file exactly did you alter? You can easily change the wrong file.

Comment: @LexLi there is a common iis config file under documents/iisexpress which I modified. Not the solution config

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#add-iis-express-from-visual-studio-2015-2017-solution-file If you never knew which file used by VS2015, you ignored something important.